# Remove group by field

Tags: group-by, db2

I've got an issue while getting data from DB2.  I want to summarise the invoice amounts by customer.  In one field, (calculated - I've called this InvoicedThisYear) it works out what was invoiced this year and in another it works out what was invoiced in the previous year (calculated, I've called it InvoicedLastYear).  However, as it is summariesed I've grouped it by the Cust, but it is also wanting the data grouped by the InvoiceYear, so I've had to include this in the grouping.  My problem is in my results I now have zeros for the years where there is no data and duplicates, e.g.:

```
Cust     InvoicedThisYear   InvoiceLastYear
abc          0                 100
abc          100                0
```

Ideally I would like to see

```
Cust   InvoicedThisYear     InvoicedLastYear
abc        100                  100
```

Here is my code:

```
SELECT 
   Cust AS Customer,
   (CASE WHEN InvoiceYear = Year(Current Date) THEN sum(InvoiceAmt)ELSE 0 END) as InvoicedThisYear,
   (CASE WHEN InvoiceYear = year(Current Date)-1 THEN sum(InvoiceAmt)ELSE 0 END) as InvoicedLastYear
FROM 
    InvHead
GROUP BY 
   Cust, 
   InvoiceYear
HAVING
   ((CASE WHEN InvoiceYear = Year(Current Date) THEN sum(InvoiceAmt)ELSE 0 END)<>0)
   OR
   ((CASE WHEN InvoiceYear = year(Current Date)-1 THEN sum(InvoiceAmt)ELSE 0 END)<>0)
ORDER BY 
   Cust
```

How do I get the desired result?  The query will not run if I remove the groupby Invoice Year

As a size note, it works in MS Access without grouping by the Invoice Year!

Thanks,

Michael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the `SUM()` around the case statements:

```
SELECT 
   Cust AS Customer,
   sum(CASE WHEN InvoiceYear = Year(Current Date) THEN InvoiceAmt ELSE 0 END) as InvoicedThisYear,
   sum(CASE WHEN InvoiceYear = year(Current Date)-1 THEN InvoiceAmt ELSE 0 END) as InvoicedLastYear
FROM 
    InvHead
GROUP BY 
   Cust
ORDER BY 
   Cust
```